# How can I determine how much of modal VC is covered by the keyboard on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a modal view controller that I am presenting on iPad via:

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle  = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:newDetailController animated:YES];
```

There are editable fields on the new VC. When I edit the field, the keyboard appears and covers up a chunk of the underlying VC.

How can I determine how much of the VC is obscured by the keyboard? On iPhone, this is simple as the presented VC is full-screen and the keyboard math is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a UIView method to convert coordinates from a view's coordinates system to another's. Use that to get the coordinates of your view in the coordinate system of your UIWindow, that's the system the keyboard uses, and it should become a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can possibly put your view inside a subclassed UIScrollView that is designed to avoid the keyboard. Here is a link to some more info about the class: https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

So you can just drop the .h and .m files into your project, if you are using IB then create a UIScrollView in IB and change it's class to TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView. Otherwise just allocate and initialize and new TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView and place your UIView inside it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Just saw the answer by @rad182 as I was posting this, sorry haha

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to solve this problem is to use https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding
Works very well :D